# mapnik npm fails on freebsd

Tags: node.js, freebsd, mapnik

I'm trying to install mapnik on FreeBSD system with npm command 
`npm i mapnik` .
After all I receive next message 
`npm ERR! mapnik@3.5.13 install: node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the mapnik@3.5.13 install script 'node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build'.`

I tried to find solution of this problem, but I did not find anything that can much help me.
Thanks for all responses!

Comment: How did you install `node` and `npm`?

Answer (score 1):

In most cases the FreeBSD port of Mapnik (located in /usr/ports/graphics/mapnik) will work. However, if the port is broken, or you'd like to install another version the following instructions will help.

You will need to install the following ports/packages to ensure that mapnik will compile for you:

```
graphics/png
graphics/tiff
graphics/jpeg
graphics/proj
devel/icu
print/freetype2
graphics/cairo
graphics/cairomm
print/harfbuzz
devel/pkg-config
graphics/py-cairo
devel/boost-python-libs
devel/libtool22
devel/libltdl22
```